# Avoid request problems with the Google Maps API(localhost)

Tags: javascript, php, localhost, geocode

I have a problem trying to use Google Maps API in my code.

The problem is that with my code and my API KEY without restrictions, I get an ERROR: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error.Althought if I put restrictions to my API KEY(localhost,https://localhost,https://localhost:80....)I have an ERROR: REQUEST_DENIED.

function geocode($address){

```
// url encode the address
$address = urlencode($address);

// google map geocode api url
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address= 
{$address}&key=AIzaSyDZaPEOrHX1Xd0VfiX2aV2xfn7_XeHiSls";

// get the json response
$resp_json = file_get_contents($url);

// decode the json
$resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);

// response status will be 'OK', if able to geocode given address 
if($resp['status']=='OK'){

    // get the important data
    $lati = isset($resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']) ? 
    $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] : "";
    $longi = isset($resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']) ? 
    $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'] : "";
    $formatted_address = isset($resp['results'][0]['formatted_address']) 
    ? $resp['results'][0]['formatted_address'] : "";

    // verify if data is complete
    if($lati && $longi && $formatted_address){

        // put the data in the array
        $data_arr = array();            

        array_push(
            $data_arr, 
                $lati, 
                $longi, 
                $formatted_address
            );

        return $data_arr;

    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

else{
    echo "<strong>ERROR: {$resp['status']}</strong>";
    return false;
}
```

}
?>

```
<!-- google map will be shown here -->
<div id="gmap_canvas">Loading map...</div>
<div id='map-label'>Map shows approximate location.</div>

<!-- JavaScript to show google map -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js? 
key=AIzaSyDZaPEOrHX1Xd0VfiX2aV2xfn7_XeHiSls"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init_map() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <? 
            php echo $longitude; ?>),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new 
        google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), 
        myOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php 
        echo $longitude; ?>)
        });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<?php echo $formatted_address; ?>"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>

<?php
```

Comment: At least for the php code, you want to allow access from the hostname (or ip) of the server that is running that code. It probably is not localhost since that is not a publicly accessible address.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to access from my local server. So it is not possible to use the google map api from a local server?(my localhost)